# How to disable google chrome image delay download?

Tags: google-chrome

When I visit a webpage with many pictures, chrome doesn't automatically download all those images until I scroll the the webpage and show the image location.

Question> Is it possible that I can setup so that chrome will download all images within a webpage whenever I visit a URL?

Thank you

Version 102.0.5005.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Some websites are really _long_, like 'infinite scrolling'. Not sure if this could ever work and even if, it would probably take an infinite amount of time?

Comment: This sounds more like lazy loading implemented on the web page. It's not specifically Chrome doing it, but how the website is implemented. You can try setting the Chrome flag `#enable-webassembly-lazy-compilation` or looking for an anit-lazy loading extension that's still updated. For the sake of performance, I'd probably advise against trying to disable lazy loading.